# highcharts series type 'flags' do not show point out of series

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have use highcharts series type 'flag' and have some data points.
I have a situation when my data points list from e.g. [-100;100]
But some flags value are out of this range. I cannot find any solution do show these flags which out of range.

Comment: Hi @Vahe Akhsakhalyan, Could you reproduce that problem in some online code editor? You can start from: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/4hoxbcwp/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/gamotfh3/2/ Look at this

Answer (score 0):

The flag is not located on the `line` series because the x value is outside the range:

```
series: [{
    id: "data",
    data: [
        [1569269259533, 100],
        [1569269319534, 100]
    ]
}, {
    type: 'flags',
    useHTML: true,
    y: -18,
    id: 'flags',
    onSeries: 'data'
}],
chart: {
    events: {
        load: function(e) {
            var flagSerie = this.get('flags');
            flagSerie.setData([{
                x: 1569269299533,
                count: 3
            }]);
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/rmonx6Lz/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/series.flags.onSeries

Comment: yeah I understand that it is outside of  range. I would like to draw it in line, despite the fact that it is out of range

Comment: One more interesting note, using my example drag from right side splitter and note than the flag will came to line.

Comment: Hi @Vahe Akhsakhalyan, A flag from the beginning must be on the graphic part of a series. You can always use `y` property instead of `onSeries`. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/xpkyo2j1/